# How to copy from putty and paste in another program

Tags: centos, clipboard, putty

I'm using putty in `Centos` in order to connect to another `Centos` server. The `copy/paste` functions of putty in `Centos` is weird! I tried to select text to copy text and right click to paste it. The copy is ok but the past doesn't work(I've tried middle mouse button too). I googled it and found that pasting does work with Ctrl+Shift+Insert. That works fine.

I've tried to paste a text which i copied in putty before in another program(for example in the web browser) but the `clipboard` is the same as before copying in putty.

I'm wondering, how can I copy some text in putty and paste it in a browser in `Centos`.

Comment: Why putty and not the native ssh clients?

Comment: I can't use native ssh client, because I use a key file for connection(ppk), and I get this error with native ssh client: `Permissions 0644 for 'testdev.ppk' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: testdev.ppk
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`

Comment: https://techtuts.info/2014/06/convert-ppk-id_rsa-linux/ convert it to id_rsa following the tutorial; then `mkdir ~/.ssh ; mv id_rsa ~./ssh ; chmod 700 ~/.ssh ; chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa` ; then you will be able to use the native ssh client.

Comment: I've installed putty from rpm and I'm using centos: `sudo yum install putty
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.plusline.de
 * epel: mirror.imt-systems.com
 * extras: wftp.tu-chemnitz.de
 * updates: ftp.plusline.de
Nothing to do
` and `pyttygen testdev.ppk -O private-openssh -o id_rsa pyttygen: command not found...`